# Sending Powermail Form as PDF

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, powermail

i want to create a PDF with all the Informations set in the Powermail Form. When i **Submit** the Form, the PDF should be sent to the Receiver.

I actually dont know what i should do now. What could be a Solution.

**Environment:**

- TYPO3 9.5.4
- Powermail 7.2.2
- pdfviewhelpers 2.0.2

Does anybody already did something like that and could tell me what should be the right way to realize a setup like this?

I appreciate every helpful answer or suggestions

Comment: Hi @ChrisKr or @bschauer, do you guys have thoughts on this now that some time has gone by? I'm wanting to do that same thing. I was hoping that `pdfviewhelpers` would export a PDF from `powermail` but it appears it doesn't do that out of the box. I'm looking at `powermailpdf` as a solution but it appear to have less of a following that `pdfviewhelpers` but not sure why.